# Select In and Out in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the in and out of employee in one column, and getting his rendered hours. This is the actual data of my time table. Then I want to left join `time_Tb` to `task_Tb` do get `In/Out` in one column.

time_tb

```
Txn_id  Date                    Status   UserID
0001    2020-04-24 08:00:00.00  IN       1
0001    2020-04-24 10:00:00.00  OUT      1
0002    2020-04-24 10:30:00.00  IN       1
0002    2020-04-24 11:30:00.00  OUT      1
```

What I want to display, left join the `time_tb` to `task_tb` and display `In/Out` in column per `txn_id`.

```
task_tb

    UserID  Txn_id   TaskID      
    1       001      COD          
    1       002      COD  


my expected output:


   UserID  Txn_id TaskID  In/Out    
     1       001    COD    2020-04-24 08:00:00.00  -  2020-04-24 10:00:00.00   
     1       002    COD    2020-04-24 10:30:00.00   -  2020-04-24 11:30:00.00
```

Comment: how are you calculating `Time Rendered`?

Comment: by using datediff

Comment: Post your expected output as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your `task_tb` table to the `time_tb` table twice, once to get the `IN` time, and once to get the `OUT` time. Since it's possible the `OUT` record may not be present, we use a `LEFT JOIN` for that one. Once you have joined twice, you can just `CONCAT` the `Date` values to get the `In/Out` column:

```
SELECT tk.UserID, tk.Txn_id, tk.TaskID,
       CONCAT(tm1.Date, ' - ', tm2.Date) AS "In/Out"
FROM task_tb tk
JOIN time_tb tm1 ON tm1.Txn_id = tk.Txn_id AND tm1.UserID = tk.UserID AND tm1.Status = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN time_tb tm2 ON tm2.Txn_id = tk.Txn_id AND tm2.UserID = tk.UserID AND tm2.Status = 'OUT'
```

Output:

```
UserID  Txn_id  TaskID  In/Out
1       1       COD     2020-04-24 08:00:00.00 - 2020-04-24 10:00:00.00
1       2       COD     2020-04-24 10:30:00.00 - 2020-04-24 11:30:00.00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=acf096e8d503316db04fd51af7332cf3)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use `lead()`?

```
select t.*,
       concat(date, '-', next_date) as in_out
from task_tb t join
     (select ti.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by user_id, txn_id order by date) as next_date,
      from time_tb ti
     ) ti
     on t.txn_id = ti.txn_id and t.user_id = ti.user_id
where ti.status = 'IN';
```

This assumes that in/out are properly interleaved.  If that is not the case, you should ask a NEW question, with appropriate sample data and explain what to do in various edge cases.